# protect sem_wait() from signals using pthread_sigmask()

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have a library that accesses a hardware resource (SPI) via a 3rd party library. My library, and in turn the SPI resource, is accessed by multiple processes so I need to lock the resource with semaphores, the lock functions are below:

```
static int spi_lock(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == -1)
    {
        syslog(LOG_ERR,"failed to read clock: %s\n", SPISEM, strerror(errno));
        return 3;
    }
    ts.tv_sec += 5;
    if (sem_timedwait(bcoms->spisem, &ts) == -1)
    {
        syslog(LOG_ERR,"timed out trying to acquire %s: %s\n", SPISEM, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static int spi_unlock(void)
{
    int ret = 1;

    if (sem_post(bcoms->spisem))
    {
        syslog(LOG_ERR,"failed to release %s: %s\n", SPISEM, strerror(errno));
        goto done;
    }
    ret = 0;
done:
    return ret;
}
```

Now my problem is the library is used in a daemon and that daemon is stopped via a kill signal. Sometimes I get the kill signal while I am holding the semaphore lock and hence the servers cannot be restarted successfully because the lock is perpetually taken. To fix this I am trying to block the signals as shown below (I am waiting for hardware to test this on atm):

```
static int spi_lock(void)
{
    sigset_t nset;
    struct timespec ts;

    sigfillset(&nset);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &nset, NULL);

    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == -1)
    {
        syslog(LOG_ERR,"failed to read clock: %s\n", SPISEM, strerror(errno));
        return 3;
    }
    ts.tv_sec += 5; // 5 seconds to acquire the semaphore is HEAPS, so we better bloody get it !!! 
    if (sem_timedwait(bcoms->spisem, &ts) == -1)
    {
        syslog(LOG_ERR,"timed out trying to acquire %s: %s\n", SPISEM, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static int spi_unlock(void)
{
    sigset_t nset;
    int ret = 1;

    if (sem_post(bcoms->spisem))
    {
        syslog(LOG_ERR,"failed to release %s: %s\n", SPISEM, strerror(errno));
        goto done;
    }

    sigfillset(&nset);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &nset, NULL);
    ret = 0;
done:
    return ret;
}
```

But having read the man pages for sigprocmask() it says in a multi-threaded system to use pthread_sigmask(), and one of the servers I want to protect is will be multi threaded. What I don't understand is if I use pthread_sigmask() in the library, and the main parent thread spawns a SPI read thread that uses those locking functions in my library, the read thread will be protected, but can't the main thread still receive the kill signal and take down the daemon while I am holding the mutex with the signals disabled on the read thread getting me no where? If so is there a better solution to this locking problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's how I've dealt with this problem in the past on another OS. The server cleans up the semaphore when it starts. That could mean 1) deleting the semaphore, and creating a new one 2) using the "create" flag when the server opens the semaphore, or 3) just using a control function to reset the semaphore to its initial state.

Comment: You may want to lock a file while you "own" the device rather than using a semaphore. A file lock will automatically be removed when the process owning it is terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your approach will work. You can not block SIGKILL or SIGSTOP. Unless you are saying that the daemon is getting a different signal (like SIGHUP). But even then I think it's bad practice to block all signals from a library call. That can result in adverse effects on the calling application. For example, the application may be relying on particular signals and missing any such signals could cause it to function incorrectly.

As it turns out there probably isn't an easy way to solve your problem using semaphores. So an alternative approach is to use something like "flock" instead. That solves your problem because it is based on open file descriptors. If a process dies holding an flock the associated file descriptor will be automatically closed and hence will free the flock.

Comment: Blocking signals from library code is perfectly acceptable and idiomatic. It does not cause them to be lost. It briefly defers them during critical sections that the signal could interfere with, nothing more.

Comment: Are you sure? The sigprocmask manual page says: "If  SIGBUS,  SIGFPE,  SIGILL,  or  SIGSEGV are generated while they are blocked, the result is undefined, unless the signal  was  generated  by kill(2), sigqueue(3), or raise(3)"

Comment: None of those can be generated except by invoking undefined behavior anyway, so there's no problem.

Comment: That's not really true. When writing a library you can't (in general) control what the application context is. For example, the application could be doing some specific memory management off the SEGV signal.

Comment: If you block the signal only during execution of your library code, there is no reason for any of these signals to be generated except possibly a bug in your library code or the caller violating the contract of your library code. In either case the behavior is already undefined anyway.

Comment: No that's not always the case. You just can't know what the application requires beforehand. I already gave you an example. Here it is in more detail - the application overrides malloc so that it only ever gives out write protected pages. Then on first write it catches the SEGV, does some specific memory management, remaps the page writeable and restarts the faulting instruction. That is, the assumption that SEGV is always due to a bug is not necessarily correct.

Comment: Redefining malloc or any other standard function results in UB.

Comment: Really?? That's a total assertion. In any case, that was just an example and not the point. Anyway, I guess we are going off topic. We'll agree to differ on this one then.

Comment: Yes. From the list in Annex J, "The program declares or defines a reserved identifier, other than as allowed by 7.1.4 (7.1.3)." Anyway yes let's just agree to differ.

Comment: The flock seems to be the right route to look at, and it avoids blocking signals all together, which from your discussion above may or may not be messy. I just wish the flock api was as evolved as the sem api, ie had a timedwait option etc :)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you've analyzed the problem correctly - masking signals does not protect you. Masking signals is not the right tool to prevent process termination with shared data (like files or shared semaphores) in an inconsistent state.

What you probably should be doing, if you want to exit gracefully on certain signals, is having the program install signal handlers to catch the termination request and feed it into your normal program logic. There are several approaches you can use:

1. Send the termination request over a pipe to yourself. This works well if your program is structured around a `poll` loop that can wait for input on a pipe.
2. Use `sem_post`, the one async-signal-safe synchronization function, to report the signal to the rest of the program.
3. Start a dedicated signal-handling thread from the main thread then block all signals in the main thread (and, by inheritance, all other new threads). This thread can just do `for(;;) pause();` and since `pause` is async-signal-safe, you can call any functions you want from the signal handlers -- including the pthread sync functions needed for synchronizing with other threads.

Note that this approach will still not be "perfect" since you can never catch or block `SIGKILL`. If a user decides to kill your process with `SIGKILL` (`kill -9`) then the semaphore can be left in a bad state and there's nothing you can do.